# Empty a list every 7 days

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a bot, the bot listens to messages on slack. It counts how many times a user messaged in a specific channel every 7 days.

To count the occurrence I am using the slack event listener.

Here is my code.

```
user_messages = []

def count_messages():
    user_messaged.append(username)

    return Counter(user_messages)



scheduler(func=count_messages, interval = 7 days)


user_messages = []
```

Every 7 days run the function.

Make the list empty after the function was ran so the appending the usernames to list can start for the next seven days.

How can I flush the list after the scheduler calls the function which is every 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

try [time lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

from there on, you have various option. Like taking the localtime and check for the delay you want or go with the sleep function, etc.